# Existe alguma diferença em utilizar o método Read() do objeto SqlDataReader?

Tags: c#

Estou executando o trecho de código abaixo, porém, fiquei com dúvida relacionada ao método `Read()` do objeto SqlDataReader.

```
using (SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
{
    if (reader.HasRows)
    {
        if (reader.Read())
        {
             pconfigWS.Usuario = reader["usuario"].ToString();
             pconfigWS.Senha = reader["senha"].ToString();
             pconfigWS.EndConWSPorto = reader["endConWSPorto"].ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

Gostaria de saber se existe diferença em usar `While(reader.Read())`, `if(reader.Read())` e `reader.Read()`

Sei que o resultado da query será apenas uma linha, porém, estou com essa dúvida.

Alguém sabe dizer ?

Obrigado

Comment: Pelo o que eu entendo cara, a diferença e que se você usar while read, ele vai passar registro por registro que você trouxer do banco suponhamos que você trouxe 10 registro em um select ele passa um por um, o if read ele vai ler apenas o primeiro independente de quantos voce trouxe isso se existir registro para ler, caso nao exista ele passa pelo if, de usar direto sem if nem while, ele vai ler o primeiro registro apenas, porem se nao trouxer nada e vc tentar usar ele vai te lançar uma exceção.

Comment: Então Jhonatan, entendi o seu comentário e já fiz esse teste, porém, minha dúvida é se existe uma regra de utilização ou se existe boas práticas para esse caso entende.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cada chamada a `Read()` vai avançar a leitura dos resultados da pesquisa.

Nesse caso, a diferença seria:

```
//contiuna lendo o próixmo até não houver mais
while (reader.Read())
{
  ...
}

//lê o próximo e me fala se for sucedido...
if (reader.Read())
{
  ...
}

//lê o próximo
reader.Read();
```

Acho importante saber que `if(reader.Read())` vai avançar até o próximo registro, então o próximo `reader.Read()` vai ser o registro **seguinte**, não o atual.

Por exemplo, seu códio explicado:

```
using (SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
{
    if (reader.HasRows) //verifique se o leitor tem dado algum
    {
        if (reader.Read()) //lê os dados - se tiver mais de um registro, não está sendo lido
        {
             pconfigWS.Usuario = reader["usuario"].ToString();
             pconfigWS.Senha = reader["senha"].ToString();
             pconfigWS.EndConWSPorto = reader["endConWSPorto"].ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

E um exemplo que pode dar resultados inesperados:

```
using (SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
{
    List<PConfigWS> resultados = new List<obj>();
    if (reader.Read())
    {
        while (reader.Read())
        {
             var pconfigWS = new PConfigWS();
             pconfigWS.Usuario = reader["usuario"].ToString();
             pconfigWS.Senha = reader["senha"].ToString();
             pconfigWS.EndConWSPorto = reader["endConWSPorto"].ToString();
             resultados.Add(pconfigWS);
        }
    }
}
```

Nesse caso, o primeiro registro seria ignorado (por causa do `if(reader.Read()`), que provavelmente não seria o resultado desejado. Usar `reader.HasRows` seria a maneira certa, como você usou.

Não há necessariamente 'boas práticas' entre essas funções - são literalmente a mesma função, sendo utilizada em formas diferentes. Tudo depende se você está lendo apenas um registro ou vários.

Comment: disculpe aí o portugês, não é o meu idioma natal

Comment: Obrigado pela sua explicação, minha dúvida foi tirada.

Comment: @brazilianldsjaguar Eu alterei "recordes" pra "registros", eu não tenho certeza sobre Portugal, mas aqui no Brasil recorde usamos "recorde" [com outro significado](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recorde) - eu até tentei consultar um pessoal no chat, mas não tem ninguém de Portugal lá. De qualquer forma, ainda é possível reverter a edição se isso for comum por lá. No mais, muito boa resposta e seu português =D

Comment: @jbueno obrigado - na verdade eu estava traduzindo a palavra inglesa "record" - registro realmente explica melhor. :)

Comment: Sim, eu percebi =D